# Not able to fix checkmarx scanner issue

Tags: checkmarx, security-scanner, source-scanner

I am trying to fix checkmarx scanner issue in different ways but nothing helps to fix FLS Update and Crete.
Below are the things I tried

```
         if(Schema.sObjectType.ProviderRecordQuestion__c.fields.CPAHomes__c.isUpdateable() && Schema.sObjectType.ProviderRecordQuestion__c.fields.CPAHomes__c.isCreateable())
                {
                    questionObj.CPAHomes__c = cpaHomeId;
                   
                }
                if(Schema.sObjectType.ProviderRecordQuestion__c.fields.Actor__c.isUpdateable() &&  Schema.sObjectType.ProviderRecordQuestion__c.fields.Actor__c.isCreateable() )
                {
                    questionObj.Actor__c = stractorId;
                }
                
                if(Schema.sObjectType.ProviderRecordQuestion__c.isCreateable() && Schema.sObjectType.ProviderRecordQuestion__c.isUpdateable())
                {  
                    questionId = DMLOperationsHandler.getIdAfterInsertSOQL(questionObj);
                }
```

like this also

```
                ProviderRecordQuestion__c questionObj = new ProviderRecordQuestion__c();
                questionObj.CPAHomes__c = cpaHomeId;
                questionObj.Actor__c = stractorId;
                
               
                if(Schema.sObjectType.ProviderRecordQuestion__c.fields.CPAHomes__c.isUpdateable() && 
                Schema.sObjectType.ProviderRecordQuestion__c.fields.Actor__c.isUpdateable()&&
                Schema.sObjectType.ProviderRecordQuestion__c.fields.CPAHomes__c.isCreateable() && 
                Schema.sObjectType.ProviderRecordQuestion__c.fields.Actor__c.isCreateable()){
                    questionId = DMLOperationsHandler.getIdAfterInsertSOQL(questionObj);
                }
```

but still I am getting FLS Update/Create issue thru code scanner